# showing descriptions with simple carousal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a simple sliding carousal that shows an iphone with 3 screens. Each time you press the next or previous arrow, it slides to the new image. I have that part figured out, but I am having trouble displaying/hiding the text with each slide. Right now, all three text descriptions are showing.

```
$(function () {
var onSlide = 0;
var moveSlide = 0;
var imageWidth;
    $('.iphone-overlay .nav-left')
        .on('click', function () {
            if (onSlide > -1) {
                onSlide--;
                doStuff();
            };
        })
    $('.iphone-overlay .nav-right')
        .on('click', function () {
            if (onSlide < 1) {
                onSlide++;
                doStuff();
            };
        })

    function doStuff() {
        console.log(onSlide);
        imageWidth = $('.banner-slider img').width();
        moveSlide = (imageWidth / 3) * onSlide;
        $('.banner-slider img').css('left', moveSlide);
    }
```

});

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WnQ7S/

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with it a couple of hours and came up with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WnQ7S/3/).

All of the text is hidden in a .holder.

Then when the different images are moved, the equivalent text is moved into a div below the picture.

The way the images were looped and counted had to be changed.

Here's the relevant JS

```
$(function () {
    var onSlide = 0;
    var moveSlide = 0;
    var imageWidth;
        $('.iphone-overlay .nav-left').on('click', function () {
                onSlide = onSlide - 1;
                if ( onSlide < 1 )
                {
                 onSlide = 3;
                 }
                 doStuff();
                                                                });
        $('.iphone-overlay .nav-right').on('click', function () {
                onSlide = onSlide + 1;
                if ( onSlide > 3 )
                {
                 onSlide = 1;
                 }
                 doStuff();
            });

        function doStuff() {
            console.log(onSlide);
            imageWidth = $('.banner-slider img').width();
            moveSlide = (imageWidth / 3) * onSlide;
            $('.banner-slider img').css('left', moveSlide);
            $('.putmehere').html('');
//            alert(onSlide);
            $('.putmehere').append( $('.holder .slide' + onSlide).html() );
        }

});
```

Comment: Nice! The text is showing properly. However now the slider itself is misbehaving. I can't seem to scroll from left to right properly anymore.

Comment: It might be worth it to rethink the organization. If you have one div with a series of images, and another div with a series of text divs (like you have now), then as you click buttons you can grab an image and a matching text and place them in a visible div.

Comment: Here's a simple fiddle that might let you rethink your overall code. http://jsfiddle.net/8a7Mm/6/